# Passing along information on a FileReference Complete event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

I need to pass along a string with my FileReference, or provide that string as an argument when an event fires. To be clear, it really annoys me that AS3 doesn't allow you to pass parameters on events.

Right now, I've extended the FileReference class to include an additional variable. I'm trying to get this to compile, but it won't compile; I think I don't know how to import this class correctly. If you can tell me how to import this class correctly so that I no longer get `Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant` at compile time that would be great.

This is the extended FileReference class:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;

public class SxmFR extends FileReference {

  public var housenum:String = "";

  public function SxmFR(str:String) {
      housenum = str;
      super();
  }
}
```

I've tried that in a .mxml and a .as in the same folder. Neither is automatically imported.

I've also tried to extend the Event class, but I couldn't figure out how to make the event dispatch, since I need to respond to the `Event.COMPLETE` event. If you can tell me how to make it dispatch on this, it also might work.

Please help me get this figured out, and much love and thanks to all involved. : )

Comment: Which type was `not found or was not a compile-time constant`? Are you able to import other classes?

Comment: I am able to import native Flash classes -- I think the problem is that I don't really know how to import external classes of custom make.

SxmFR is the `not found` type. I instantiate objects to that type in a couple of places, because I want to attach the value of housenum to that FileReference.

Comment: Just to clarify: You have this code surrounded in a `package {}` statement and the file name is `SxmFR.as`, right?

Comment: The filename is `SxmFR.as` but I do not have the code surrounded in a `package{}` statement. Is that necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is. All public classes should be surrounded by appropriate `package{}` statements. Classes in the root folder of the class path use `package{}` and files in nested folders (for ex: nested/path/File.as) use `package nested.path{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your event listener as a closure you have access to the variables in the current function:

```
function myFunction(): void {
    var aParam: String = "This is a parameter";

    dispatcher.addEventListener("eventName", function (e: Event): void {
        // you can access aParam here
        trace(aParam);
    });
}
```

The `aParam` inside the function will have the same value as it had when `addEventListener` was called.

Comment: Hmm... this almost works. I am using a for loop to iterate over this, but it seems to use the same object initially created in the first pass of the loop, because it always tries to apply the first value of `aParam` to subsequent events assigned by the same loop. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: If you loop over an array `a` you can use `a.forEach` instead. That will create a new variable for each iteration of the loop. See my answer on this question for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715918/in-actionscript-3-how-can-i-pass-the-current-value-of-an-array-in-a-loop-to-an-e/1718024#1718024